# awk Compare 7 files, print match and difference based on Fileds:

Tags: unix, awk

I need to comapre 7 files Ref.txt and Jan.txt to Jun.txt and obtain matches, and non-matches, for this case 
I am looking to check Second field of Ref.txt with all the First field of Jan.txt to Jun.txt,if yes then print all the fileds of Ref.txt (Master dump), 
then print the entire line of Jan.txt to Jun.txt. And for no match found on Jan.txt to Jun.txt to state "NotFound" .

Ref.txt

```
abc 10  xxyyzz
bdc 20  xxyyzz
edf 30  xxyyzz
ghi 40  xxyyzz
ofg 50  xxyyzz
mgf 60  xxyyzz
```

Jan.txt

```
10  Jan 100
30  Jan 300
50  Jan 500
```

Feb.txt

```
10  Feb 200
20  Feb 400
40  Feb 800
60  Feb 1200
```

Mar.txt

```
20  Mar 600
50  Mar 1500
```

Apr.txt

```
10  Apr 100
30  Apr 300
50  Apr 500
```

May.txt

```
10  May 200
20  May 400
40  May 800
60  May 1200
```

Jun.txt

```
20  Jun 600
50  Jun 1500
```

Desired Output:

```
Ref.txt Ref.txt Ref.txt Jan.txt Jan.txt Jan.txt Feb.txt Feb.txt Feb.txt Mar.txt Mar.txt Mar.txt Apr.txt Apr.txt Apr.txt May.txt May.txt May.txt Jun.txt Jun.txt Jun.txt
abc 10  xxyyzz  10  Jan 100 10  Feb 200 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    10  Apr 100 10  May 200 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound
bdc 20  xxyyzz  Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    20  Feb 400 20  Mar 600 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    20  May 400 20  Jun 600
edf 30  xxyyzz  30  Jan 300 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    30  Apr 300 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound
ghi 40  xxyyzz  Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    40  Feb 800 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    40  May 800 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound
ofg 50  xxyyzz  50  Jan 500 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    50  Mar 1500    50  Apr 500 Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    50  Jun 1500
mgf 60  xxyyzz  Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    60  Feb 1200    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound    60  May 1200    Notfound    Notfound    Notfound
```

Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Thank you in retrospect for the readability of your post.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting problem.  We were bored to death.

Comment: Why is there no `10  Apr 100` in the expected output?

Comment: Hi 10 Apr 100 considered in the Desired Output, Have changed the desired output, sorry

Comment: How much money are you going to pay for the solution?

Comment: sorry to say, dont have huge money

Comment: Beginner of Unix and thought to learn complex things from experts ..

Comment: The 100% right tool for this job is awk and you can learn it from the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins. You can also google for examples, especially anything posted at the comp.lang.awk newsgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a gift: please ask questions for stuff you don't understand

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 { 
        printf "%s %s %s\t", FILENAME, FILENAME, FILENAME 
        if (NR > FNR) file[++num_files] = FILENAME 
    }
    NR == FNR {
        id[NR] = $2
        ref[NR] = $0
        num_ids++
        next
    }
    { value[FILENAME,$1] = $0 }
    END {
        print ""
        for (row=1; row<=num_ids; row++) {
            printf "%s\t", ref[row]
            for (f=1; f<=num_files; f++) {
                key = file[f] SUBSEP id[row]
                printf "%s\t", (key in value ? value[key] : "Notfound")
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' {Ref,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun}.txt
```

```
Ref.txt Ref.txt Ref.txt Jan.txt Jan.txt Jan.txt Feb.txt Feb.txt Feb.txt Mar.txt Mar.txt Mar.txt Apr.txt Apr.txt Apr.txt May.txt May.txt May.txt Jun.txt Jun.txt Jun.txt 
abc 10  xxyyzz  10  Jan 100 10  Feb 200 Notfound    10  Apr 100 10  May 200 Notfound    
bdc 20  xxyyzz  Notfound    20  Feb 400 20  Mar 600 Notfound    20  May 400 20  Jun 600 
edf 30  xxyyzz  30  Jan 300 Notfound    Notfound    30  Apr 300 Notfound    Notfound    
ghi 40  xxyyzz  Notfound    40  Feb 800 Notfound    Notfound    40  May 800 Notfound    
ofg 50  xxyyzz  50  Jan 500 Notfound    50  Mar 1500    50  Apr 500 Notfound    50  Jun 1500    
mgf 60  xxyyzz  Notfound    60  Feb 1200    Notfound    Notfound    60  May 1200    Notfound
```

Comment: +1 Nice. It is still puzzling why each row of expected output of the OP, contains `1+6*3=19` elements (whereas your solution contains `1+6=7`) :)